# DalekJS: Firefox browser opens, tests don't run

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, functional-testing, dalekjs

When I try to run Dalek tests in Firefox, Firefox browser only opens, but no tests are run. Anybody else run into this? Same test works fine in Chrome and PhantomJS.

My test is extremely basic:

dalektest.js

```
module.exports = {
    "Page title is correct": function(test){
         test.open("http://localhost:8080")
         .assert.title().is("Title", "it has title")
         .done()
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{ 
   "name": "Dalek-Tests",
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "devDependencies": {
       "dalek-browser-chrome": "0.0.1",
       "dalek-browser-firefox": "0.0.1",
       "dalekjs": "0.0.1"
   }
}
```

Dalekfile.json

```
{
    "browsers": [{
         "firefox": {
            "path": "/Applications/FirefoxAurora.app"
         }
     }]
}
```

I have all these files in the same folder and I attempt to run with these commands:

```
dalek dalektest.js -b firefox
dalek dalektest.js -b chrome
dalek dalektest.js -b phantomjs
```

Others work fine, but Firefox just opens Firefox, nothing happens after that.

I'm on Max OS X Lion. Firefox Aurora is 24.0a2 (2013-08-04)

Could not tag this properly with 'dalekjs' due to being newbie...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realized that I made a mistake when I published the 0.0.1 version of the Firefox Plugin, I will push an update to 0.0.2 this evening.

So it is not you, it shouldn't work for everyone & I didn't realized it before publishing, because I worked in my dev environment.

Thx for reporting.

Also, the Firefox Driver is even more Pre-Alpha-Alpha than the Rest of Dalek, you will experience a few methods that do not work yet.

I will highlight that on the page and on twitter.

Regards
Sebastian

Comment: Sorry, I found some more issues with Firefox & won't be able to work on them until sunday. Sorry, but I promise next week Firefox will be ready for some test fun.

Comment: So finally, I upgraded the Firefox plugin with the help of some nice Mozillians. It is now capable of running any NightlyDebug (Not Aurora) builds.

I updated the [docs](http://dalekjs.com/docs/firefox.html)

Thanks again for being so patient, I hope you can give the Dalek/Firefox Combo another try :)

Comment: Got things working now. Unfortunately cannot upvote this due to my newbie reputation, so I have to thank you like this. Looking forward to putting dalek in to use.